# Summarizing Likert-type Data

Tags: continuous-data, likert

I used a questionnaire with several questions on a five point scale (never, rarely, sometimes, often, always) to determine how well a person liked their job. I then assessed the average scores for each person and categorized these into 3 (low, medium and high) to assess the frequencies in each group. I did max -min/3 and split the variable into low: 1 to <2.33, medium: >=2.33 to <3.67, high: >=3.67 to 5. Is this valid? I didn't want to use tertiles because I thought tertiles via proc rank in SAS will simply split the sample into 3 equal groups which is not my goal.

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to compare the group who answered you questions (a) with another group? (b) with some sort of established population value? If not, what will you do with the the summarized scores about which you're asking? Can you give the bigger picture for this work?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @BruceET. This is descriptive statistics for a population. No comparisons here. I'm using a psychometric measure with 4 sets of questions to elicit the variable I'm interested in, .i.e., whether a person liked their job or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for a way to summarize opinions (expressed on answers to several questions) of each person into a single score. The first instinct might be to take each subject's average score, but that would treat ordinal categorical Likert
data as numerical, which is at best controversial.

My first suggestion would be to use each subject's median score is the subjects summary response. Your proposed manipulation of each subject's responses results in one of three categories L/M/H for each subject's summary response.

Any method of summarizing
data for each individual will result in loss of some information. Not knowing the
number of questions each subject answers or knowing how you would treat occasional
unanswered questions in determining subjects' summary scores, it is hard to say
which method is better (median or L/M/H).

My guess is that 'median' loses less
information. For example, a profoundly dissatisfied employee might give you five `never`s, which I suppose you would code as `L`, thus somewhat diluting the strength of the subject's dissatisfaction.  Not sure from your description which L/M/H category
would result from two `never`s and three `rarely`s. I am sure the median of that is
`rarely`.

In the end it is clear that L/M/H gives you only three ordinal satisfaction categories, whereas medians could potentially give you more detail (spanning values
from `1` through `5`, with some possible npn-integer summaries depending on the
number of questions each subject answers).

I can't say how much truly relevant information your L/M/H system would lose. It's your project and so you get to say how to summarize. (With whatever disclosure you want
to provide in your report/paper.) But at the very least I'd like to urge you to look
at several dozen subject-- enough to get good intuition whether the L/M/H summaries are doing
what you expected/desired of them.

Finally, I am not sure what kind of tests you will use in your final analysis of your
data. In my experience, what kind of summary score is used for individuals can make a difference whether significant effects are found. I suspect that the controversial (and I believe
often indefensible) use of averages for ordinal data persists precisely because it is thought
more likely to yield "significant" results than medians. I have no basis for judging the results from your L/M/H summary scores. The point is that the method of summarizing sometimes does matter in the final interpretation of Likert data.

Comment: Thank you so much @BruceET. I will ponder on your insightful comments.